# Blackberry MapField showing "No Data"

Tags: blackberry

Been searching for ages and can't find something that explains why this is happening.

I am trying to add a MapField to my application, but when it loads it just says No Data.

```
MapField mMapField;
Coordinates mCoordinates;
mCoordinates = new Coordinates(28.135085, -25.900461, 0);
mMapField = new MapField();
mMapField.moveTo(mCoordinates);
mMapField.setZoom(3);
add(mMapField);
```

BB Maps works on my device and Simulator, but this MapField works on neither the simulator or the actual device, I have a BIS data plan on the device.

Any help will be appriciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code that I use, which works on both the [simulator and the device](http://blog.sarmobile.ca/2011/07/software-comming-together-with-time.html) is:

```
    MapField _map = new MapField();
    Coordinates _location = new Coordinates(45.0, -75.0, 0);
    _map.moveTo(_location);
    _map.setZoom(6);
    add(_map);
```

So perhpas you should use:

```
MapField mMapField;
Coordinates mCoordinates;
mCoordinates = new Coordinates( -25.900461, 28.135085, 0);
mMapField = new MapField();
mMapField.moveTo(mCoordinates);
add(mMapField);
```

Comment: You don't answer my question, you just copy my problem and paste my code as the answer??

Comment: Look closer. In your code you do not tell the MapField which location to display, so it wil display 0.0, 0.0, 0 at the default zoom level. There is only ocean at that location. Did you try my version? If so were the results any different?

Comment: I still only get a map which says No Data in a grid repeated in each block of the grid. The coords I pass is in South Africa and I know we have support for BB Maps in South Africa. My post is a bit out dated because the code on my actual machine contains the moveTo function and a setZoom function. Will edit my post now

Comment: OK. I can replicate the No Data tiles on an OS 5 device. In my case, zoomed out to the world view the dark grey countries show No Data when zoomed in close enough. I have South Africa data as well, but many contries on the continent are dark grey. I can only conclude that your coordinates are wrong. 28.1, -25.9 is 28.1N 25.9W and is West of the Canary Islands in the Atlantic Ocean. -25.9, 28.1 is in Johannesburg and probably what you want.

Comment: Don't worry about it. We've all been there. Some times it is hard to see the forrest for the trees. This is why code reviews exist.